# Why System.exit(0) does not work in NetBeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

I use NetBeans (under Windows) and in my GUI program I add a "Close" button. And On the button, I press the right-key of the mouse -> Events -> Action -> actionPerformed. And in the code, I make it as below.

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    System.exit(0);
}
```

But after run, I pressed the "Close" button, the program didn't exit. Instead, it was blocked, I cannot close it any more. Why and how to handle it?

While doing the same program under Linux NetBeans, the 'System.exit' works well, does this mean I need to reinstall NetBeans under Windows? Or anyone has the same problem?

Plus: Below code means the jButton2 events had been registered to ActionListener, it was automatically added by NetBeans.

```
        jButton2.setText("Close");
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                        jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
                }
        });
```

Comment: Rather than call `System.exit`, have you considered hiding and disposing all top-level containers in use? That should also help.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** First, did you **register** this close button with the `ActionListener` ?

**2.** Let the `Event Dispatcher Thread` (EDT) **only handle the GUI**, don't do any process over here.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using a JFrame to build your GUI. In that case an easy way to handle this is to add the following line;

```
 jFrameName.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```